# Angular unit test combineLatest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, jestjs, combinelatest

I have started off with unit testing with Jest Framework in Angular since a while now. However i am stuck in a situation where I need to unit test **combineLatest** RxJS operator. My component looks like below.

Component:

```typescript
public userData;
public productData;

constructor(
    private readonly userService: UserService,
    private readonly productService: ProductService
) {}

public ngOnInit() {
    this.initialize();
}

public initialize() {
    combineLatest([
        this.userService.getUserData(),
        this.productService.getProductData()
    ])
    .subscribe([userData, productData] => {
        this.userData = userData;
        this.productData = productData;
    });
}
```

I have mocked both my services and my unit test looks like below.

```typescript
it('should initialize user and product data', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(userService, 'getUserData');
    spyOn(productService, 'getProductData');
    component.initialize();
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(userService.getUserData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(productService.getProductData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.userData).toBeDefined();
    expect(component.productData).toBeDefined();
}));
```

This test fails with **Received: undefined.** But the same kind of test works when working with a single observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try and answer the question in a different approach.

Lets take a look at your code, It is easier to test simple chunks of code rather that test long code.

It will be much easier to assign the variables to your properties. With that you can simply test the property

See Below improved code;

```typescript
constructor(
    private readonly userService: UserService,
    private readonly productService: ProductService
) {}
userData: any;
productData: any;
userData$ = this.userService.getUserData().pipe(
  tap(userData => this.userData = userData)
);
productData$ = this.productService.getProductData().pipe(
  tap(productData = productData => this.productData = productData)
)

v$ = combineLatest([this.userData$, this.productData$]).pipe(
  map(([userData, productData]) => ({ userData, productData }))
)
initialize() {
  v$.subscribe()
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.initialize();
}
```

### Back to your initial testing

Lets now try to test your initial code and understand why the test is not working.
From the official [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest#when-any-observable-emits-a-value-emit-the-last-emitted-value-from-each)

> When any observable emits a value, emit the last emitted value from each

Lets have a look at the below code

```typescript
    spyOn(userService, 'getUserData');
    spyOn(productService, 'getProductData');
```

Does the above code emit any value? The answer is no, so the code `this.userService.getUserData()` and `this.productService.getProductData()` will not return any value hence no value will be emitted. `combineLatest` will hence not emit any value.

### Solution

You will need to return an `Observable` from the `spyOn()` function, something like
spyOn(userService, 'getUserData').and.returnValue(of({}));

Now the Observable will emit and the test will pass

### Final proposal for a better code.

You may consider using `async` pipe to handle your subscription. With `async` pipe your code can be written as below

```typescript
constructor(
    private readonly userService: UserService,
    private readonly productService: ProductService
) {}
userData$ = this.userService.getUserData()
productData$ = this.productService.getProductData()
v$ = combineLatest([this.userData$, this.productData$]).pipe(
  map(([userData, productData]) => ({ userData, productData }))
)
```

In your html

```html
<ng-container *ngIf='v$ | async'>
  {{ v.userData | json }}
  {{ v.productData| json }}   
</ng-container>
```

In your test file you can have

```typescript
it('should initialize user and product data', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(userService, 'getUserData').and.returnValue(of({}));
    spyOn(productService, 'getProductData').and.returnValue(of({}));
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.v$.subscribe({
      next: (v) => {
        expect(v.userData).toBeDefined();
        expect(v.productData).toBeDefined();
      }
    })
}));
```

The above test simply checks that if we subscribe to `v$`, then the `userData` and `productData` are defined

Answer (score 2):

You can mock `combineLatest` in `jest` like this

```js
/* Mock rxjs's combineLatest */
const rxjs = jest.requireActual('rxjs');
rxjs.combineLatest = jest.fn(() => of(<ADD_YOUR_MOCK_DATA_HERE>));
```

###### Update: you can also mock using `spyOn`

```js
jest.spyOn(rxjs, 'combineLatest')
      .mockReturnValue(of(<ADD_YOUR_MOCK_DATA_HERE>));
```

Full test looks something like this

```js
it('should initialize user and product data', () => {
  const userMockData = <ADD_MOCK_DATA>;
  const productMockData = <ADD_MOCK_DATA>;

  /* Mock rxjs's combineLatest */
  const rxjs = jest.requireActual('rxjs');
  rxjs.combineLatest = jest.fn(() => of([userMockData, productMockData]));
  
  //or mock using spyOn
  jest.spyOn(rxjs, 'combineLatest')
    .mockReturnValue(of([userMockData, productMockData]));

  jest.spyOn(userService, 'getUserData');
  jest.spyOn(productService, 'getProductData');

  component.initialize();

  expect(component.userData).toEqual(userMockData);
  expect(component.productData).toEqual(productMockData);
});
```

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot set property combineLatest of [object Object] which has only a getter`

Comment: @Marcel unfortunately for me `requireActual` returns `any`, so I tried to add type manually, I got the error but not the above one, I have added one more way to mock it using `spyOn` works fine for me even with type